# How do I log smartmeter register data over TCP for elster A100c and A1100

Tags: c++, logging, tcp

I am currently working on a project but am currently struggling with compiling a program to be able to log register data from an Elster A100c and A1100. I want to know how I can go to work on transferring this data over a TCP connection rather than IrDA to log data on my laptop. Logging data for these specific meters seems to be quite tedious.

Any ideas help or suggestions on how I can complete this using C++ ?